# Where do Progress / QAD "TMPxxxx" numbers come from?

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

We have several processes which generate temporary references in the form
"TMPxxxx" where x is a digit. These appear to be used for session
temporary file names, and for keys in the usrw_wkfl table. I¹m not sure if
these are generated by QAD (MFG/Pro), or Progress, or just by the individual
programs.

A colleague has suggested they come from Progress/Openedge, but I can't find
anything in the documentation, or any references on the web either for QAD
or Progress, hence this question.

If there is a standard process within Progress/Openedge or QAD for this ­could
somebody point me in the right direction please?

Thanks!

Comment: There was a routine provided with one of the "ADM" frameworks a million or so years ago.  I don't recall what it's name was.  And i have no idea if QAD actually uses it.  They could have just rolled their own pretty easily.

Answer (score 1):

TMPxxxx session id is created by QAD(MFG/PRO) an ERP application.
There is an Security control menu item (mostly menu number: 36.3.24) in MFG/PRO (QAD) and field that name is "Session ID Prefix".

It's used for temporary system-generated work file (creation when login, deletion when logout). Exp: qad_wkfl, sr_wkfl and some file creation in temp directory.

You can monitor users who get TMP id for which session.

```
for each mon_mstr no-lock:

display
    mon_userid      column-label "Mfg/Pro User ID"
    mon_program     column-label "Mfg/Pro Program Name"
    mon_sid         column-label "Mfg/Pro Temp Session Id"
    mon__qadi01     column-label "Progress Session Id".

end.
```

Maybe too late but I hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

OpenEdge creates various temporary files while the session is active. Each file has a 3-character prefix followed by a random number. The different prefixes are:

- dbi: Stores temporary tables
- lbi: Local before-image file (subtransaction undo)
- ped: Edit buffer contents
- rcd: Cache of r-code being run in a session
- srt: Temporary sort space; session compile storage
- trp: Stores Data Dictionary changes until they are saved

Sometimes the random number is the process ID of the Progress session, but not always. The location of these files can be controlled with the -T startup parameter.

Here is a Progress knowledge base article about the temp files:
http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P111424

Here is the Progress online documentation:
https://documentation.progress.com/output/ua/OpenEdge_latest/index.html#page/dpabl/temporary-file-i-2fo.html

Comment: Hi TheDrooper! Thanks for this - I'd found the article you quote, which perhaps I should have mentioned in the question. These are not the temp files I'm looking for, but they do seem to be the only ones in progress documentation. What I'd understood from a colleague was that Progress provided a feature for application temporary files, but I can't find any evidence of this.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. I haven't heard of Progress application temp files, but it does have the ability to write to files. Here is an example:     `DEFINE STREAM sFile.
OUTPUT STREAM sFile TO VALUE("tmp1234.txt").
PUT STREAM sFile UNFORMATTED "Test data" SKIP.
OUTPUT STREAM sFile CLOSE.`

Comment: Nothing to be sorry about. It would seem I'm chasing shadows... :-)